# Is a member of the Loyal opposition a Minister of the Crown?

Tags: united-kingdom, terminology, member-of-parliament

Does the term 'Minister of the Crown' apply to ministers of the loyal opposition as well as those who are members of Her Majesty's Government?

Comment: No, though note that under the [Ministerial and other Salaries Act 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministerial_and_other_Salaries_Act_1975), the Leader of the Opposition and two Opposition whips get paid an additional amount on top of their MP salary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the members of Her Majesty's loyal opposition are shadow ministers.  They don't have a job in government, though they may be members of the Privy council.

Comment: Generally the only members of the opposition who will be in the Privy Council are the Leader of the Opposition, and anyone who held a ministerial post in a previous government.

Comment: @JoeC: it seems to be a bit more widespread than that; I count 6 current members of the [Shadow Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Opposition_Shadow_Cabinet_(United_Kingdom)) who have never served in government but are members of the Privy Council.

Comment: Actually, looking at the list, I am seeing a few more senior shadow cabinet ministers appointed than I was expecting.